Where does the letter "u" in modern "build" and "guild" come from?
Old English (OE), Old Norse (ON), and Middle English (ME) do not include a 'u' in these words. In guild and build, the 'u' is silent, and the 'i' is pronounced short.
Just looking at the pronunciation and actual spelling of 'build' and 'guild' because a student wrote 'bild', which is phonetically correct when listening to it.

Build: the modern spelling is unexplained: https://www.etymonline.com/word/build

Are you sure that sometime in the Late Middle English/Early Modern English period, there weren't dialects that pronounced these as bwild and gwild?

In guild, the "u" is probably there to help with pronunciation as in "guide" etc, although plenty of words have a hard g and no u, and I can't explain why. Or I guess it's possible it came from a misreading/misspelling of ME forms such as gyylde and gyeld, or Old French ghelde, gheude. Build is, as mentioned, stranger.

@StuartF I’m not so sure about the pronunciation argument since gild and guild are pronounced the same way, at least in AuE.

The Great Vowel Shift -> when in doubt, blame the Great Vowel Shift (and phonetic spelling).

For the verb build, Middle English had the spelling with the letter 'u' in some forms. It is where the modern spelling 'build' comes from. The OED offers a comprehensive history of the word build, and I'm citing some relevant sections:

Metathetic variant of Old English (weak Class I) bytlan (also weak Class II bytlian) to build, erect < bottle n.1; compare (with parallel metathesis) bold n.
Old English y, ȳ typically remained as a high front rounded vowel in the west midlands and south-west until unrounded at the end of the 14th cent. (compare Middle English forms such as bulde, builde, buyld, which provide the modern standard spelling build). However, with this particular word there is clear evidence that the western rounded pronunciation, like the western spelling, gained wider currency beyond the west and survived in some educated speech as late as the 17th cent.
Oxford English Dictionary, s.v. “build (v.), Etymology,” September 2024, https://doi.org/10.1093/OED/7399256824.

For the noun guild, the reason is different. There is no Middle English form spelled with a 'u'; the spelling with 'u' first appears in the 1600s. Here, the letter 'u' serves as a buffer to show that there is a velar ('hard') /g/ sound rather than a palato-alveolar ('soft') /dʒ/ sound (as in giant, gym) before the letter 'i' representing an original front vowel.
